# Getting an error posting a bytearray to a URL with CircuitPython

Tags: adafruit-circuitpython

I have an image loaded into a `bytearray` in a CircuitPython project, and I want to pass it to a POST request using the `adafruit_requests` library.

My code:

```py
headers={
            'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
            'Content-Length': str(frame_length),
            'Prediction-Key': prediction_key
        }

r = requests.request('POST', prediction_endpoint, data=buffer, headers=headers)
```

When I run this code, I get this error:

```sh
......Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 85, in <module>
  File "adafruit_requests.py", line 242, in request
  File "adafruit_requests.py", line 224, in request
TypeError: wrong number of arguments
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why! Whats the correct way to send a `bytearray` as an octet stream to a POST request using CircuitPython?

I've looked at the code in the Adafruit requests repo and the line numbers don't match up with the code, so I don't know what's causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is an error in the adafruit_requests library in CircuitPython. I've raised an issue and PR to fix it:

https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_Requests/issues/20

https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_Requests/pull/21